# How to run subsciber on multiple threads with RxJava on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

I am new to RxJava and struggling on a (i guess) simple problem. I want to process the subscribe part simuleasly in 3 threads. Thats why I use a FixedThreadPool. Example code:

```
Observer.just("one", "two", "three", "four")
.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3))
.subscribe(new Observer<String>() {

    public void onNext(String string) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Started: " + string);
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        Log.d(TAG, "Ended: " + string);
    }

    (...)

}
```

Expected result:

```
Started: one
Started: two
Started: three
Ended: one
Started: four
Ended: two
Ended: three
Ended: four
```

Actual result:

```
Started: one
Ended: one
Started: two
Ended: two
Started: three
Ended: three
Started: four
Ended: four
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RxJava Observables are sequential and the `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` operators won't run values in parallel with each other.

The closest thing you can achieve is by grouping values via a modulo key, run them via `observeOn` and merge the results:

```
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

Observable.range(1, 100)
.groupBy(v -> count.getAndIncrement() % 3)
.flatMap(g -> g
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .map(v ->  Thread.currentThread() + ": " + v))
.toBlocking()
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However do I understand correctly that the solution "sets separate queue" per each thread so if the tasks don't take the same amount of time then at the end some of the threads might finish earlier while one thread has still several tasks to run. My question is does RxJava support using a shared queue between multiple threads?

Comment: There is no work-stealing with this setup nor any shared queue.